# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array string given

Tags: php, wordpress

the wordpress site is giving this error in place of where the logo may be;

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in themes....\edgt.functions.php on line 337.

and the associated code

```
        //is subarray of meta array keys set?
        if(is_array($keys) && count($keys)) {
            $sub_array = array();   

            //for each defined key
            foreach($keys as $key) {
                //check if that key exists in all meta array
                if  (array_key_exists($key, $meta_data)) {
                    //assign key from meta array for current key to meta subarray
                    $sub_array[$key] = $meta_data[$key];
                }
            }

            //we want meta array to be subarray because that is what used whants to get
            $meta_data = $sub_array;
        }
```

Other information: using XAMPP to develop the website locally, and using the Hudson theme with the wordpress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question?  I'm not sure that error could be any more clear.

Comment: the error message is saying the variable "$meta_data" is of type string instead of being of type array, as would be expected for a function that checks an array for the existence of a key

Answer (score 0):

You could contact the theme developer about this warning and ask that it be fixed.

Otherwise just before this line:

```
if  (array_key_exists($key, $meta_data)) {
```

Add the following code:

```
if (!is_array($meta_data)) {
   $meta_data = [$meta_data];
}
```

That will get rid of the warning, but this may be a sign of a problem further up the chain and would require more info and time to debug.

Definitely contact the developer if you paid for this theme.